# mapstruct issue with nested entities when mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, mapstruct

Hello I have the Following mapstruct mapping description.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {
        GroupResolver.class }, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class GroupMapper {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ChainMapper chainMapper;

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
    @Mapping(target = "chains", expression = "java(mapChain(group))")
    @Mapping(target = "users", expression = "java(mapUsers(group))")
    public abstract GroupResp toModel(final Group group);

    public Set<ChainResp> mapChain(final Group group) {
        return chainMapper.toModelSet(group.getChains());
    }

    public Set<UserResp> mapUsers(final Group group) {
        return userMapper.toModelSet(group.getUsers());
    }

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
    @Mapping(target = "chains", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "users", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "users.chainUnixPaths" , ignore = true )
    public abstract Group toEntity(final GroupResp groupeResp);

    public Set<Chain> mapChains(final GroupResp groupeResp) {
        return chainMapper.toEntitySet(groupeResp.getChains());
    }

    public Set<User> mapUsers(final GroupResp groupeResp) {
        return userMapper.toEntitySet(groupeResp.getUsers());
    }

     
    
}
```

I m facing a compile time error stating that :

> No target bean properties found: can't map Collection element "UnixPathResp users[].chainUnixPaths" to "UnixPath users[].chainUnixPaths". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "UnixPath map(UnixPathResp value)".

AND

> No target bean properties found: can't map property "ServerResp users[].server" to "Server users[].server". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "Server map(ServerResp value)".

I assume that my Ignores are not Working Or my resolver is somehow fuzy.

Here is all related classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6980925916410978160L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GROUPS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GROUPS", sequenceName = "SEQ_GROUPS")
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_NAME", length = 256, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CHAIN_GROUP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHAIN_ID"))
    private Set<Chain> chains = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_GROUP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

AND

```
public class GroupResp implements Serializable{

 
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7184268214689299357L;

    @JsonProperty("GROUP_ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty("GROUP_NAME")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("CHAIN_GROUP")
    private Set<ChainResp> chains = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonProperty("USER_GROUP")
    private Set<UserResp> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Then my Generic Resolver

```
@Component
public class GroupResolver extends GenericPFResolveContract<GroupResp, Group, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long getIdof(GroupResp s) {
        return s.getId();
    }

    @Override
    @ObjectFactory
    public Group resolve(GroupResp s,@TargetType Class<Group> ts) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return super.resolve(s, ts);
    }
     
}
```

With

```
@Component
public abstract class GenericPFResolveContract<S,T,K> implements PFResolveContract<T, S> {

    @Autowired
    protected JpaRepository<T, K> sourceRepository;
    
    @Override
    @ObjectFactory
    @Transactional
    public T resolve(S s,@TargetType Class<T> ts) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
         if(s == null || getIdof(s) == null) {
             return ts.newInstance();
         }
        return sourceRepository.findById(getIdof(s)).orElseGet(()-> {
            T newInstance = null;
            try {
                newInstance = ts.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return newInstance;
        } );
    }

    public abstract K getIdof(S s);
    
}
```

Comment: I had a type I must Use `@Mapping(target = "users[].chainUnixPaths" , ignore = true )`

Comment: Maybe it comes from the `UserMapper` or the `ChainMapper`. Could you add their code please ?